# How to calculate partial eta squared using SPSS MIXED?

Tags: mixed-model, spss, effect-size, predictor

In the SPSS output when using the MIXED procedure (analyse -> mixed models -> linear) you only get the F value and the degrees of freedom. I found some formulas for estimating partial eta squared using only F and dfs (e. g. in the paper "*Calculating and reporting effect sizes to facilitate cumulative science: a practical primer for t-tests and ANOVAs*" by Daniël Lakens; https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00863).

It says you can only use the formulas if you got no covariates and no measured factors. The problem is I got several covariates in my model with a within and a between subjects factor and a few interactions (see below). How can I calculate partial eta squared (or SSerror and SSeffect)?.

Here is the Syntax:

**MIXED** Y **BY** X1 X2 **WITH** COV1 COV2 COV3

/**FIXED**=X1 X2 COV1 COV2 COV3 X1*X2 X1*COV1 X1*COV2 | NOINT SSTYPE(3)

/**REPEATED**=X2 | SUBJECT(id) COVTYPE(UN).